# Find <li> by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

```
<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li class="new">text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li class="click">text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li class="new">text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li class="click">text</li>
</ul>
```

When we click on `li.click`, how to get a first `li.new` between previous `<li>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for

```
$(this).prevAll('li.new:first')
```

Comment: @Rooney: This is the best method available. Is there a reason why it won't work for you?

Comment: @Rooney: Probably not without looping through the entire `<ul>`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li.click').click(function() {
   var new = $(this).prevAll('.new:first');
});
```